# assets relative to root, but html files are in subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, path, xampp, lamp

I have 675 html files that ahve been passed to me today.

The folder structure is as follows:

```
 - index.html
 - /assets/
 - /pages/
```

In the `pages/` folder I have the 675 html files. In each of them I have all the assets that are relative to the root folder, like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/main.css">
```

I have uploaded everything to my demo server, and the URL is like so:

```
https://example.com/CLIENT/rebrand/
```

The `index.html` page contains a list of the 675 html files in `pages` folder.

As you can imagine, when I click on one of them, I get the page, but images, js and css are not loaded.

Is there a way to instruct the server, via .htaccess maybe, to interpret

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/main.css">
```

as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/CLIENT/rebrand/assets/css/main.css">
```

I would like to avoid a massive search&replace, in so many files, because the risk is high to break something.

Do you guys have any hint on a cleaner solution? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use this redirect rule at the top of your .htaccess for this redirect:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^assets/.+$ /CLIENT/rebrand/$0 [L,NC,R=301]

# other rules appear below this line
```